# Display texture without any effects from environment

Tags: rendering, texturing

I'm making a tablet with a lightly colored UI (image texture) and for some reason eventhough I have set material surface to "Background" disabled mipmapping the texture looks washed out from a distance.

Image texture is set to Filmic sRGB so that the colors remain true to what they would be on a real-life backlit LED screen.

I want it to look completely as it would an unprocessed or untouched png (as it looks on my computer), but blender/cycles is still applying effects to it as you can see on this image:

[image]

On a closer distance, all colors and everything look normal and unprocessed:

[image]

This problem does not exist when using a dark UI:

[image]

Thanks in advance.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Connect your color directly to the material output:

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't help, results are still the same — I should include I have it set the Image texture at Filmic sRGB to keep colors true to what they would be in real life on a backlit LED screen.

Comment: @Crashtor if the color looks good up close, then it's not a matter of color transformation, because that doesn't change based on distance to camera. What happens when you render in a (much) higher resolution and then downscale? I think aliasing might be a problem here.

Comment: I have tried rendering it at 3840 * 2160 but results are the same. When the render starts everything look like it should but then as the render progresses, blender applies all types of effects to it making it look entirely unreadable.

Comment: @Crashtor do you have compositing enabled? What's your compositor node tree? Do you have bloom enabled?

Comment: @Crashtor I doubt it, because I didn't show you the compositor tree… Please share your .blend file using https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: https://blend-exchange.com/b/6B9MZaPB

Comment: https://i.ibb.co/5T4pW38/dash-Light.png this is the image

Comment: @Crashtor I can't reproduce your issue, I tried rendering with the beginning camera position: https://i.imgur.com/Fgk7jq4.png and then zooming up close: https://i.imgur.com/vzisVte.png and in both cases I sampled the blue chart bar's color, and it was the same (almost, the usual inconsistency caused by dithering): `3b6ccf` and `3b6bce`